# How to delete a report with Code or process?

Tags: reporting, automation

I want to automate a process where old neglected reports are automatically deleted if they were not run for X amount of days (if I can't do it in a variable/labal, I will do a source report.
I am not able to finalize the deletion of the report.

If I try with Flow - the 'Report' object is not available on the list of delete objects
[image]

If I try with Apex, (while testing code only) - I am getting that DML operation is not allowed on Report

```
Report[] reportsToDelete = [SELECT Id FROM report 
                         WHERE Id = '00O1o0000053rtwEAA']; 
try {
    delete reportsToDelete;
} catch (DmlException e) {
    // Process exception here
}
```

[image]

I also tried with Database class: same error

```
Database.DeleteResult reportsDR = Database.delete('00O1o0000053rtwEAA', false);
```

Any other option ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Report` is not a data sObject, but rather metadata. It can't be deleted like  a regular record.

To delete reports, you would need to make a callout (as a user that has permission to alter metadata) via the [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_resources.htm) or the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deleteMetadata.htm), or perform a Metadata API destructive deployment.

Comment: +1 The URI would be something like `DELETE /services/data/v47.0/analytics/reports/00O6F00000FW8mRUAT` returning 204 No Content as response on success

Comment: Thank you. I can confirm the url is as @Swetha mentioned.